# Word 2003 overrides all formatting in HTML

Tags: html, ms-word, dreamweaver

Every time I edit a HTML document in MS Word 2003, it replaces all the inline styling I have done to the file in Dreamweaver. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word is not a text editor. It adds lots of formatting on its own. You need to use a text editor. There's one built into your system, but you might want to get something that's a little more powerful than Notepad or TextEditor.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write code in a plain text editor. I prefer Sublime Text 2. http://www.sublimetext.com/2